# Wcf Improving data transfer speed

Tags: performance, wcf, file-transfer

I'm building a Torrent client application. 
By now, the clients were on same machine and exposed their services by NetTcpBinding.
Each client connected other clients with **Localhost** address so going through router was not necessary; Transfer speed was OK (**4 MB/S +-**) - Do you think its slow?

Method that returns a peace of the file from a client (Client's service):

```
public byte[] GetBytes(int TorrentID, int Position, int ArrayLenght=1024*55, ref int Read)
```

From when the clients connected to other clients with **external IP**, the speed went down (All clients on same machine). I do understand that now the data have to go through router but the speed is so low (**200-300KB/S !**).

What is the problem?

***Update 1:***

1. For now, there are 2 clients. The first download from the second.
2. The max bandwidth on my network is 200 MB (20 MB/S inside my local network) and IPS is 100 MB (10 MB/S from outside).

***I will update if any other details are required.**

Comment: How many clients? What is the bandwidth on your network? Also keep in mind that when you are using localhost the the networkstack takes a shortcut.

Comment: Yeah I saw the difference while using localhost address (much faster but still not great).

Comment: Why are you passing that array (byte) by reference? Why don't you just return a byte array? That way  you don't have to pass the array in both directions.

Comment: @RQDQ I did change but the speed still the same - 1 MB/S +-.

Comment: @rene I updated the topic for the detailed you requested.